# How to do pattern matching for erlang string (list)?

Tags: erlang

I have one string `"{request, {M, F, A}}"`, I know its type is list, but I can't do pattern matching by using [..]. How can I extract `request`, and `{M, F, A}` from it?

Comment: Are M, F, and A varying here, or do you mean the specific characters "M", "F", and "A"? If they are varying, you need some more flexible kind of parsing; pattern matching is not powerful enough for that. Same with the request part - is it an atom, or a field that can vary? erl_scan:string() followed by erl_parse:parse_term() might be all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pattern match on the beginning of a string. You might try something like this:

```
1> Strip = fun(Input) -> lists:reverse(tl(lists:reverse(Input))) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.54118792>
2> Parse = fun(Input) ->
2>    "{" ++ Tail = Input,
2>    case Tail of
2>       "request, " ++ MFT -> {request1, Strip(MFT)};
2>       "request2, " ++ MFT -> {request2, Strip(MFT)}
2>    end
2> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.54118792>
3> Parse("{request, {M, F, A}}").
{request1,"{M, F, A}"}
4> Parse("{request2, {M, F, A}}").
{request2,"{M, F, A}"}
5>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain that the string will look exactly like `"{request, {M, F, A}}"`, you can match it like so:

```
[_, $r, $e, $q, $u, $e, $s, $t, _, _, ${, $M, _, $F, _, $A, $}, _] = "{request, {M, F, A}}"
```

You can play around this